# Rails RSpec fails when trying to test a model within a controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have searched a lot to see if there is a solution to this issue, I have not seen anyone reporting this issue, let me add that I am a rails novice.

Ruby Version: 3.2.2
Rails Version: 7.0.5.1
Rspec Rails Version: 6.0.0

**the controller:**

```rb
def index
    books = Book.all.limit(limit).offset(get_books_params[:offset])

    render json: BooksRepresenter.new(books).as_json
end
```

**the test:**

```rb
RSpec.describe Api::V1::BooksController, type: :controller do
  it 'has a max limit of 100' do
    expect(Book).to receive(:limit).exactly(1).times.with(100).and_call_original

    get :index, params: { limit: 999 }
  end
end
```

**the output of the test:**

```bash
Failure/Error: expect(Book).to receive(:limit).exactly(1).times.with(100).and_call_original
     
(Book(id: integer, title: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, author_id: integer) (class)).limit(100)
           expected: 1 time with arguments: (100)
           received: 0 times
```

So from what I can see the test is expecting the call to come from `Book`, but because `Book.all` is called before `.limit` it would seem that the expect does not recognise `.limit` being called.

Any help/explanations would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `all` is not needed here. So you can do `Book.limit(limit).offset(get_books_params[:offset])`

Answer (score 0):

All is not required here

just do `books = Book.limit(limit).offset(get_books_params[:offset])`

Remove the all and then do

```
before do
  allow(Book).to receive(:limit).and_call_original
end

it do
  expect(Book).to have_received(:limit).exactly(1).times.with(100)
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the input, I have tried

`expect(ActiveRecord::Relation).to receive(:limit).exactly(1).times.with(100).and_call_original`

resp:

`Failure/Error: expect(ActiveRecord::Relation).to receive(:limit).exactly(1).times.with(100).and_call_original
       ActiveRecord::Relation does not implement: limit
`

I wanted to know,is it possible to test both limit and offset in one single test

I can get limit to test if I do this 
`books = Book.limit(limit).offset(get_books_params[:offset])`

however I get a fail if I also try to test `offset` in the same test